# Material UI - Unblock scrolling when popover is opened

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, popover

The scroll is blocked with Popover according to the new material-ui version doc.

When i open the popover, the scroll-bar of the web page suddenly disappeared and it's not the part of user experience in my opinion.

I wanna keep the scroll bar visible while popover is open.

I'm using Material-UI V3.8.1.

Comment: I don't think the main issue with default behavior (without container being set), is disappearing scrollbar, rather than that, the scroll to the top effect is problematic and affecting the UX.

Answer (score 11):

it can be fixed by using container props of Popover.
container props is a node, component instance or function that returns either.
The container will passed to the Modal component.
By default, it uses the body of the anchorEl's top-level document object, so it's simply document.body most of the time.
This default setting is making document removing scroll bar.
So i just used its direct parent for container instead of default setting and it solved the problem. :)

```
<Popover
  open={...}
  anchorEl={...}
  anchorOrigin={...}
  container={this.AnchorEl.parentNode}
>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you attach it to the parent node it won't move with the node when you scroll

Comment: What is `this.AnchorEL`?

Comment: replace it with the element you attach the menu to

Answer (score 8):

The property you are looking for is called `disableScrollLock`. But using this, does not recalculate the modals positioning and you will have a floating modal in your application. Instead, as described by a few others here, the `Popper` should be used.

Answer (score 4):

To implement the correct behavior you can use **Popper** with **Clickawaylistener**

Answer (score 2):

### My solution:

```
<Popover
  ...
  // mui version 5.14.0
  slotProps={{
    root: {
      sx: {
        overflowY: "scroll",
        overflowX: "hidden"
      }
    }
  }}
  // older mui versions
  classes={{
    root: {
      overflowY: "scroll",
      overflowX: "hidden"
    }
  }}
>
  ...
</Popover>
```

---

### Long story long:

#### Problem code:

```
<Popover
  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  onClose={handleClose}
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: "bottom",
    horizontal: "left",
  }}
>
  ...
</Popover>
```

#### Problem visualized:

Original state of right side of page:

[image]

When the `Popover` is opened, the vertical scrollbar disappears:

[image: ![enter image description here]

### Reason:

This happens because the `Popover` is inserted in the DOM as a sibling of the `#root` `div`, not its child:

[image]

This inserted DOM element occupies the exact entire width and height of the page, therefore, it does not need to have scrollbars:

[image]

### My objective:

Since the suddenly introduced gap by the missing scrollbar looks shabby, I wanted to still have the scrollbar shown on the screen, but not scrollable. This is in line with what `MUI` has by default - when a `Popover` is open on the screen, the screen does not scroll.

Basically, here's what I wanted:

[image]

---

### Solution attempt 1:

I noticed that when the `Popover` is open, a `padding-right` of `17px` is automatically introduced on the document's `body` element:

[image]

Tried removing this `padding-right` from the `body`:

[image]

This caused the scrollbar to disappear without leaving a gap when the `Popover` is open, and reappear when the `Popover` is closed.

The appearance and disappearance of the scrollbar was causing the remaining elements on the screen to reposition themselves whenever the `Popover` was toggled:

[image]

[image]

No-go.

### Solution attempt 2:

```
<Popover
  ...
  disableScrollLock={true} // Added
>
  ...
</Popover>
```

This did cause the scrollbar to stay on the screen when the `Popover` is open, but, as Viktor has mentioned in his answer, it caused the `Popover` to float around when the page was scrolled.

[image]

No-go.

*A third possible attempt could have been to use `<Popper />` with `<ClickAwayListener />` as others have mentioned in their answers. But I didn't want to go back and change all instances of `Popover` across my app.*

### Final solution:

`mui` version `5.14.0`:

```
<Popover
  ...
  // mui version 5.14.0
  slotProps={{
    root: {
      sx: {
        overflowY: "scroll"
      }
    }
  }}
  // older mui versions
  classes={{
    root: {
      overflowY: "scroll"
    }
  }}
>
  ...
</Popover>
  ...
</Popover>
```

This allows the scrollbar to remain shown on the page while not allowing the user to scroll:

[image]

### Caveat (and resolution):

For the right-most *Button* (Button 6), the `Popover` was introducing a horizontal scrollbar on the page, with a carry-over of `1px`:

[image]

To resolve this, either prevent horizontal scrolling on the `Popover`'s `root`:

```
<Popover
  ...
  // mui version 5.14.0
  slotProps={{
    root: {
      sx: {
        overflowY: "scroll",
        overflowX: "hidden" // Added
      }
    }
  }}
  // older mui versions
  classes={{
    root: {
      overflowY: "scroll",
      overflowX: "hidden" // Added
    }
  }}
>
  ...
</Popover>
```

Or move the `Popover`'s `root` `1px` to the left:

```
<Popover
  ...
  // mui version 5.14.0
  slotProps={{
    root: {
      sx: {
        overflowY: "scroll",
        left: -1 // Added
      }
    }
  }}
  // older mui versions
  classes={{
    root: {
      overflowY: "scroll",
      left: -1 // Added
    }
  }}
>
  ...
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, it looks like if you want to retain the scroll bar, then you should use Popper instead of Popover.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but Popper has click away property which is not desirable in my project. is there any other way using Popover?

Comment: When your Popover/Popper is displayed, what action(s) do you want to trigger making it go away?

Answer (score 1):

I found another Solution that fits my case:

Just added a `useEffect` and attached a mouse wheel attempt to it close the popover:

```
function myPopover({/*..your props..*/}){
    const [open,setOpen] = useState(flase);
    //.... your rest of the code
    function handleClose(){
         setOpen(false);
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(open){
            document.body.onwheel = handleClose; 
            document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', handleClose, false);

        }
        return ()=>{
            document.body.onwheel = undefined;
            document.body.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleClose, 
                   false);
        }
    },[open])
    return <Popover
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      anchorEl={...}
      anchorOrigin={...}
      /*... your props */
    >
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question when trying to fix the same problem. Improving upon @Tommy's answer, I've found a working solution:

```
const NewPopover = (props) => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef();

  // Box here can be any container. Using Box component from @material-ui/core

  return (
    <Box ref={containerRef}>
      <Popover {...props} container={containerRef.current}>
        Popover text!
      </Popover>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried something now that seems to work.
Use a Popper instead I have done something like this.

```
<Popper
    id={id}
    open={popoverOpen}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    placement="top-start"
    disablePortal={false}
    modifiers={{
      flip: {
        enabled: false
      },
      preventOverflow: {
        enabled: true,
        boundariesElement: "scrollParent"
      }
    }}
>
```

Then to get the click away desired effect mount a "mousedown" effect check if the popover is open if it is then check the click is inside of the popper element. If not close the modal.

Something like this for the mousedown effect, note remember to dismount it or you'll get a leak.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (anchorEl) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick)
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick)
    }
   // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
   return function cleanup() {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick)
   }
}, [anchorEl])

const handleClick = event => {
    if (!document.getElementById(id).contains(event.target)) {
       setAnchorEl(null)
       setCustomOpen(false)
    }
 }
```

Also just incase you are unsure theres another difference with Popper and Popover and that's just adding a Paper, but i don't need to explain how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this with

```css
html {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Since Material-ui adds `style="overflow: hidden;"` on the `html` tag.